# Avoid too many SOQL calls in APEX Select COUNT()

Tags: apex, soql, limitexception

I am trying to create a count summary of all calls logged by a specific sales rep (as Task) for each of his prospects (e.g. 8 calls for prospect A, 14 for B, etc.) using Apex.
Below is what I got so far, unfortunately, Salesforces complains: "Too many SOQL calls":

```
List<Contact> prospects = [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE OwnerId = '00651000003CWWpAAO'];
for(Contact c: prospects){
    List<AggregateResult> countResult = [SELECT COUNT(Activity_Type__c) FROM Task WHERE WhatId = :c.Id AND Activity_Type__c  = 'Call']; 
    System.debug(countResult[0].get('expr0'));
}
```

What's a better way to approach this and get the desired data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an additional GROUP BY to get all the values at once.

```
List<Contact> prospects = [SELECT id FROM Contact WHERE OwnerId = '00651000003CWWpAAO'];
Map<Id, AggregateResult> results = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>(
  [SELECT COUNT(Id) callCount, WhoId Id 
   FROM Task 
   WHERE WhoId = :prospects AND Activity_Type__c = 'Call' 
   GROUP BY WhoId]
);
```

You can then loop through each contact and get the result from the Map.

Answer (score 6):

You are running a SOQL query in a loop, which violates the first principle of bulkification. Simply move the query out of the loop and use `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT COUNT(Activity_Type__c) count, WhatId
FROM Task
WHERE WhatId IN :prospects AND Activity_Type__c  = 'Call'
GROUP BY WhatId
```

Then your `AggregateResult` records will have `count` and `WhatId` properties you can access to get the total for each Contact.

(Side note: Are you sure you want to be querying `WhatId`? Contact relationships should be in `WhoId`).